# Shorthand for typesafe-adding properties of one object to another

Tags: typescript

Assuming that we have an object `x` of type `X` and an object `y` of type `Y`.

How can I merge (set all properties) of `y` into `x` so that if `Y` is not a subtype (partial) of `X`, the compiler complains?

NOTE: `Object.assign(x, y)` technically works, but will not complain if `Y` contains properties that are not part of `X`.

I am hence looking for a kind of `{...x} = y`.

EDIT:

Reassigning to `x` should not be done since that would alter the identity of `x`and `x` could be `const`.

Comment: `x = {...x, ...y}`?

Comment: It should not reassign to x because x could be a const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that will complain if one type is not a subset of the other

```
//U is a subset of T
function merge<T extends U, U>(a:T, b:U):T{
  return {...a, ...b}
}
```

If you want to overwrite a you can use

```
function merge<T extends U, U>(a:T, b:U):T{
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(b)) {
    a[key as keyof U] = value
  }
  return a;
}
```

The following cases demonstrate how it works

```
type A = {a:string, b:number, c:boolean}
type B = {a:number, b:number}
type C = {b:number, c:boolean}
type D = {a:string, d:string}

let a:A = {a:"Hi_a", b:1, c:true}
let b:B= {a:99, b:2}
let c:C = {b:3, c:false};
let d:D = {a:"Hi_d", d:"Low_d"}

let ab = merge(a,b) //compiler fail - Type B prop is incompatible
let ac = merge(a,c) //passes type C is a subset of type A
let ca = merge(c,a) //compiler fail - type A is a superset of type C
let ad = merge(a,d) // compiler fail - Type D has an extra property
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqA8AVRVADylTABMBnRAVQBpaA+ACgEMAuPBgI3ZoEpOAbwBQiROlRQQ6JEIB0i1g0XzuAXxGaRoSLAQoM2AEz5CJMlVoMaLDl0S8BwsYmBx0iZhASUoiAG0Aa1QATwYAN1YAGxBUAF1EOGBEAHluACtUaHkyKHQYVEpmbn5+RFFxcVZgsMRWahDQ5NpEgF5EKNjUV01xSWlZeoBuLRERKFCAB1REAEFEDqEOPwKwTB52MBBkbgwGCHZuODho1FYwTUmZxAAhRYqObd39xy2dvfQr6dmAYQehLxnp8DkcTmcLt8bgARAErfIwdYMcjsVaIzDaM7+DgLJYcABEAAkYAB9Vj4zYARlB+Timixb1uePYAE4WZtjPSpIhDv8lrwAMyg4AxSiodSjBko2HMomk8gUxAo-EAGTgAHcSQrMdzWNwHmgsKg2HRSogAPTmnzIKYwM6eEV2xAAWkQeB+d0QU3QcCmiBg1ER1qmrFg3DOIgZrAgBqMxuUEHKlpDlDF1Guf391FYiEoIG4Yv8LQz80j3IgOY6huw3jorCTVrgNrtGDcrCdrpLCwD9VzIBm6ELSRSJd+Zex5FjRpN5AbPKbtvtbY7bo9sIAFg16khiPkc97fRhJuMo9xjFOTCazZbgy2He3oi7Vzd7ge-T2gwvQzBwz0oxBzyrONjBNRMLXNFM00QUcs17PMC25YsPTmcceVYQDDCNECIDrBtbyXR1H07ZDYJzPMByHJCbjHKNyAw6tUBA5RZ3A+dmwIh8n3dGFEE3bMdxIdB9x9AdJiAA)

Comment: The function should modify x and not create a copy (merge into).

Comment: Updated by adding a function that merges into and returns a